# Check if there are numbers around a keyword in a text file

Tags: python

I am having a text file 'Filter.txt' which contains a specific keyword 'D&O insurance'. I would check if there are numbers in the sentence which contains that keyword, as well as the 2 sentences before and after that.

For example, I have a long paragraphe like this:

"International insurance programs necessary for companies with global subsidiaries and offices. Coverage is usually for current, future and past directors and officers of a company and its subsidiaries. **D&O insurance** grants cover on a claims-made basis. How much is enough? What and who is covered – and not covered? "

The target word is "D&O insurance." If I wanted to extract the target sentence (*D&O insurance grants cover on a claims-made basis.*) as well as the preceding and following sentences (*Coverage is usually for current, future and past directors and officers of a company and its subsidiaries*. ***and*** *How much is enough?*), what would be a good approach?

This is what I'm trying to do so far. However I don't really know how to apply to find ways to check in the whole sentence and the ones around it.

```
for line in open('Filter.txt'):
    match = re.search('D&O insurance(\d+)',line)
    if match:
        print match.group(1)
```

I'm new to programming, so I'm looking for the possible solutions for that purpose.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you add a sample of the contents of `Filter.txt` to the question?  Also could you then show what results you'd expect from the sample?

Comment: @TlsChris Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my question. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't do a lot of text processing.  I'd look to make a list of sentences but I'm not sure how to do that.  Full stops appear in abbreviations and sentences can end on question marks too.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm going to take a stab at this. Assume `string` is the entire contents of your .txt file (you may need to clean the '/n's out).

You're going to want to make a list of potential sentence endings, use that list to find the index positions of the sentence endings, and then use THAT list to make a list of the sentences in the file.

```py
string = "International insurance programs necessary for companies with global subsidiaries and offices. Coverage is usually for current, future and past directors and officers of a company and its subsidiaries. D&O insurance grants cover on a claims-made basis. How much is enough? What and who is covered – and not covered?"
endings = ['! ', '? ','. ']
def pos_find(string):
    lst = []
    for ending in endings:
        i = string.find(ending)
        if i != -1:
            lst.append(string.find(ending))

    return min(lst)
def sort_sentences(string):
    sentences = []
    while True:
        try:
            i = pos_find(string)
            sentences.append(string[0:i+1])
            string = string[i+2:]
        except ValueError:
            sentences.append(string)
            break

    return sentences

sentences = sort_sentences(string)
```

Once you have the list of sentences (I got a little weary here, so forgive the spaghetti code - the functionality is there), you will need to comb through that list to find characters that could be integers (this is how I'm checking for numbers...but you COULD do it different).

```py
for i in range(len(sentences)):
    sentence = sentences[i]
    match = sentence.find('D&O insurance')
    print(match)
    if match >= 0:
        lst = [sentences[i-1],sentence, sentences[i+2]]
        for j in range(len(lst)):
            sen = lst[j]
            for char in sen:
                try:
                    int(char)
                    print(f'Found {char} in "{sen}", index {j}')
                except ValueError:
                    pass
```

Note that you will have to make some modifications to capture multi-number numbers. This will just print something for each integer in the full number (i.e. it will print a statement for 1, 0, and 0 if it finds 100 in the file). You will also need to catch the two edge cases where the D&O insurance substring is found in the first or last sentences. In the code above, you would throw an error because there would be no i-1 (if it's the first) index location.